# Existence of multi-variable $p$-adic $L$-functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, l-functions, iwasawa-theory

What's the "state of the art" in constructing multi-variable p-adic L-functions for number fields?

More precisely: if K is a number field, and $K_{\infty} / K$ is an infinite Galois extension, unramified outside a finite set S of primes of K, containing the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$ - extension K<sub>cyc</sub> of K and whose Galois group G is abelian with an open subgroup isomorphic to ${\mathbb{Z}_p}^d$ for some $d$, then does there exist an element of the Iwasawa algebra $\mathbb{Z}_p[[G]]$ (or some localisation of it) whose values at finite order characters χ of $G$ are the special values of the Hecke L-functions $L_S(\chi, 1)$ (with the Euler factors at primes in S removed)?

When K is totally real Leopoldt's conjecture forces $d = 1$; but I'm interested in other cases. I know there is a 2-variable Iwasawa main conjecture for imaginary quadratic fields, which I understand has been proved by Rubin, but I'm just asking about the existence of the L-function (not about any connection to annihilators of class groups). What is known in this direction for more general $K$?

Comment: Hey David. I don't know so much about this stuff, but I always found the introduction to Katz' "p-adic L-functions for CM fields" (Inventiones 49, 1978) very helpful. In particular he points out that in many cases (in this generality) the p-adic L-function should be the zero function for "trivial reasons".

Comment: Thanks, that paper is really useful and seems to answer all of my questions -- I will study it carefully. 

Comment: "I will study it carefully" is perhaps the compulsory response when your question is answered by your PhD supervisor ;-)

Comment: Hi David, I just saw this question. I guess you worked everything out, buy now, but just in case... Hida and Tilouine, for instance, discuss  $p$-adic $L$ functions for arbitrary CM fields, which have many variables (something like half of the degree plus one plus Leopoldt defect). They describe this nicely in the introduction to their _Inventiones_, 1994.