# p-adic L functions from Selmer groups - how canonical are they?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, l-functions, p-adic-numbers

For this question, I am going to be very concrete but very much appreciate broader viewpoints. Let $F$ be a number field and define $F_n = F(\mu_{p^n})$ and let us suppose for simplicity that $\mu_p \subset F$ but $\mu_{p^2} \not\subset F$ so that $Gal(F_n/F) = \mathbb Z/p^n$. In thfis case, one can consider the inverse limit $X_\infty = \lim_n Cl(F_n)[p^\infty]$ with an action of $\Gamma \cong \mathbb Z_p = \lim_n Gal(F_n/F)$.

Iwasawa showed that $X_\infty$ is essentially a torsion module over $\mathbb Z_p[[\Gamma]] \cong \mathbb Z_p[[T]]$ so that one can define a well defined characteristic ideal. In some cases, people have shown that this ideal is generated by the p-adic L-function of $F$.

**Questions:**

1. Is the expectation in general that the characteristic ideal should be generated by the p-adic L function? I am not even sure if we have a definition of a p-adic L function for arbitrary $F$.
2. To what extent can we use $X_\infty$ to pin down the p-adic L functions exactly (and not just upto units)? For instance, do people expect there to be an element $\gamma \in \mathbb Z_p[[\Gamma]]$ so that the power series $f(\gamma)$ that annihilates $X_\infty$ is exactly the p-adic L function of $F$?
3. Related to the previous point, in direct analogy with the characteristic $p$ case, one might expect that picking $\gamma$ to be the element sending $\zeta \to \zeta^\ell$ for $\ell \neq p$ might define something close to the p-adic L function. Is anything known in this direction?
4. Even if we can't capture the p-adic L function entirely, can we extract some information out of it (such as some special values) by picking appropriate $\gamma$?

Answer (score 5):

All of your questions are undermined by the same fundamental issue: *you cannot talk about "the" p-adic $L$-function in this generality, because there is no sensible definition of what a $p$-adic $L$-function should be*.

It's common to state the Iwasawa main conjecture (either the version proved by Wiles for class groups of cyclotomic extensions over totally-real fields, or its analogues in fancier settings) as an equality

"algebraic $p$-adic $L$-function = analytic p-adic L-function"

but this is perhaps a tiny bit misleading, because the two sides are not quite on the same footing.

- the algebraic $p$-adic $L$-function is an element of $\Lambda(\Gamma)$ *unique up to units*, defined as a generator of the characteristic ideal of the Selmer group;
- the analytic $p$-adic $L$-function is an element of $\Lambda(\Gamma)$ which is *uniquely determined* (on the nose), defined as the unique thing which interpolates $L$-values.

So there is **more information** on one side than the other: we should more accurately state the conjecture as saying "the algebraic $p$-adic $L$-function is the image in $\Lambda(\Gamma) / {\{\text{units}\}}$ of the analytic p-adic $L$-function". [*]

If you try to formulate main conjectures over non-totally-real fields, you find that the definition of the algebraic $p$-adic $L$-function still makes sense, but the definition of the analytic one doesn't – the fundamental problem is that if your ground field is not totally real, then $L$-functions of ray class characters don't have any critical values, so there is nothing to interpolate. [**] So there is a fundamental obstacle to extending Iwasawa main conjectures to this setting.

(A long time ago, I wondered about whether one can use Stark's conjecture, which gives an arithmetic interpretation of *leading terms* of complex $L$-functions at non-critical values, to define some kind of $p$-adic $L$-function. Here is the link: [Stark's conjecture and p-adic L-functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18884/starks-conjecture-and-p-adic-l-functions). But this is still $\pi$-in-the-sky stuff, even 13 years on from the original question: Stark's conjecture in this setting is just too hard.[***])

---

[*] This is, in fact, more or less the formulation that is used in the *noncommutative main conjectures* that were very fashionable around 2005-2010. There you have some relative $K$-group which generalises $\Lambda(\Gamma) / \{units\}$, in which there is an element arising from Selmer groups; and some other relative $K$-group which generalises $\Lambda(\Gamma)$, in which there is an element which interpolates $L$-values; and the conjecture says that the former element is the *image* of the latter under some boundary map.

[**] Over CM-fields you can do something: in this setting there exist "interesting" Hecke Grössencharacters, not of finite order, whose $L$-functions do have critical values. But if your field isn't CM and doesn't have a CM subfield, then there are no Grössencharacters whose $L$-functions have critical values. More subtly, even in the CM case, the "correct" Selmer group to match these $L$-functions turns out to be rather different from Iwasawa's $X_\infty$, and it is not obvious if it has any relation to limits of class groups.

[***] Before you ask, the recent breakthroughs on Stark's conjecture by Dasgupta et al don't help here, since they are specific to totally real / CM settings.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful! It feels strange that we can only meaningfully define p adic L functions (even conjecturally) for those fields with some archimedean condition. Feels very much against the spirit of all the places being on an equal footing.

Comment: That's an important principle but it does have limitations – one sees this much earlier on in the theory, with Dirichlet's unit theorem, where the Archimedean signature determines the rank of the unit group in an essential way.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler In the context of the unit theorem, the different places can actually be treated on essentially the same footing - $O_K^\times$ is the group of invertible sections on $Spec\, O_K$, which is a "compact curve" (the set of all places) with $r_1+r_2-1$ places removed. If you remove more places, for a total of $k$ places excluded, you will get a group of rank $k-1$, analogously to a statement for functions on punctured curves.  Of course putting those places back in is harder, but I believe there may be some analogous "Arakelov-type" statement for units bounded by $1$ at some places.

Comment: @Wojowu I've never found this viewpoint terribly convincing. Yes $Spec O_k$ behaves like a curve with some points removed; but the machinery that purports to "put them back in" is itself treating the Archimedean places in a radically different way from the non-Archimedean ones, so the claim that the resulting object restores the symmetry between arch and non-arch places seems highly suspect to me.

Comment: As expected, your answer is way better and clearer than the questions. One underlying question sort of remains: Is there an purely algebraic characterisation of the generator of the characteristic ideal that ends up being the unique p-adic L-function? In the presence of an Euler system, like the (algebraic) cyclotomic units, one could answer this with yes.

Comment: I would disagree vigorously with your implicit suggestion that Euler systems are "purely algebraic". In all cases where we have a reasonably canonical *construction* of an Euler system (not just a proof that some module of Euler systems is nonempty), this construction involves automorphic methods.

Comment: In your example, I would argue that cyclotomic units aren't a purely algebraic concept: they rely on the fact that we can generate the abelian extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ using values of a transcendental function (the exponential map).

Comment: I didn't mean that all Euler systems are algebraic. Not sure how vigorously I would claim that cyclotomic units can be viewed as purely algebraic. In any case, what I meant should be that in a few instances one can give an algebraic characterisation of the generator of the characteristic ideal without reference to L-values. It is interesting to note that in all other cases we cannot do this at the moment; we have to rely on automorphic methods. But I don't see a reason why it is theoretically impossible. I understood this as part of the question; hence my comment.

Comment: "In a few instances one can give an algebraic characterisation of the generator of the characteristic ideal" — which cases do you mean, and how?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe classical Stickelberger elements are a good choice of an annihilator of the class group and their definition can be viewed as algebraic. They fit together to a generator of the characteristic ideal of the class group.